# Recyclerview not updating ROOM sqlite data

Tags: android-recyclerview, android-sqlite, android-room

I am using ROOM database in order to add and get data from database, and using RecyclerView to show the data. The problem here is after certain updates recycler view is not showing the updated data in recycler view, however my database is updating every query properly.
One more problem is I am not able use loading while the data is update.

I am closing the database every time, I think RecyclerView is not waiting while my database is updating.

I am getting this message in info 
Could not change the database journal as DB was busy. Proceeding...
Could not change the database journal as DB was busy. Proceeding..
Just to inform I am using multiple queries in the same method

I need to know if is there any way so that I can hold the database until my query is executed completely then I can update my database, it will also help me to show "loading" to the user while the query is executing

```
private void AllStationsList() {
    if (FinalList != null) {
        FinalList.clear();
    }
    getOnlyFavourites();
    getAllWithoutFavourites();
}

private void getOnlyFavourites() {
    //Get stationList of only favourites
    StationListRepository stationListRepositoryOnlyFavourites = new StationListRepository(getApplicationContext());
    stationListRepositoryOnlyFavourites.getStationListFavourites().observe(this, new Observer<List<StationList>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<StationList> OnlyFavouritesstations) {
            assert OnlyFavouritesstations != null;

            if (OnlyFavouritesstations.size() > 0) {
                OnlyFavouritesstations = sortList(OnlyFavouritesstations);
                FinalList = OnlyFavouritesstations;
            }
        }
    });
    stationListRepositoryOnlyFavourites.closeDB();

}

private void getAllWithoutFavourites() {
    //Get stationList of all stations without favourites
    StationListRepository stationListwithoutFavorites = new StationListRepository(getApplicationContext());
    stationListwithoutFavorites.getStationList().observe(this, new Observer<List<StationList>>() {

        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<StationList> stationsWithoutFavouries) {
            Log.d("NotfavList", "" + stationsWithoutFavouries.size());
            assert stationsWithoutFavouries != null;
            if (stationsWithoutFavouries.size() > 0 || FinalList.size() > 0) {

                if (FinalList != null && FinalList.size() > 0) {
                    stationsWithoutFavouries = sortList(stationsWithoutFavouries);
                    FinalList.addAll(stationsWithoutFavouries);

                } else {
                    stationsWithoutFavouries = sortList(stationsWithoutFavouries);
                    FinalList = stationsWithoutFavouries;
                }
                Log.d("FinalListSizeActiveALL", "" + FinalList.size());
                detailsAdapter = new db_stationListAdapter(context, FinalList);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(detailsAdapter);
                /*detailsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();*/
                for (stationPostion = 0; stationPostion < FinalList.size(); stationPostion++) {
                    if (FinalList.get(stationPostion).getStationId().equalsIgnoreCase(Common.SELECTED_STATION) && onStationClick == true) {
                        Common.SCROLL_POSITION = stationPostion;
                        onStationClick = false;
                        break;
                    } else {
                        Common.SCROLL_POSITION = 0;
                    }
                }

                recyclerView.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int
                            right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight,
                                               int oldBottom) {


                        recyclerView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                onStationClick = false;
                                recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(Common.SCROLL_POSITION);

                            }
                        }, 500);
                    }

                });
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //stopLoading();
                        stopAnimation();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```